# Flutter: how to get payment status in UPI payment by android intent through deeplinking

Tags: android, flutter, dart, payment, upi

I am trying to make UPI payment by android intent through deep link by launching URL

```
  void _pay() async {
    String _url='upi://pay?pa=name@upi&pn=Name&am=1&tn=Test Payment&cu=INR';
    var result = await launch(_url);
    debugPrint(result.toString());
    if (result ==true) {
      print("Done");
    } else if (result ==false){
      print("Fail");
    }
  }
```

After opening the UPI app and making payment how would i know that payment was succesful or not, how to get the payment status?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using url directly, use library upi_pay which have the functionality to get status of payment